# ADT doesn't detect unreachable code

Tags: android, adt, unreachable-code

Got the following code in the activity:

```
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.viewid);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawableid);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    view.setBackground(drawable);
else
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Eclipse gives me an error on `setBackground`: "Call requires API level 16 (current min is 8): android.widget.LinearLayout#setBackground", and a warning on `setBackgroundDrawable`: "The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) from the type View is deprecated". I cannot compile my project with this error.

Why ADT doesn't detect that both `setBackground*` methods are valid with the version check?

Comment: You could just use the "disable check" hint, you won't have any issue then ?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot compile my project with this error.

Sure you can. Use the quick-fix to add `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)` to the method in which this code appears.